# Find words in a string between "()"

Tags: powershell

I am trying to parse a string using [regex]::matches. I am able to split the words but i am having trouble with the open and close paren. Could someone help me and explain what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advanced.

```
$results = "All domain controllers have migrated successfully to the Global state ('Start')."


[regex]::Matches($results , "\w+['a-z']") | foreach-object {$_.value}
```

Comment: `[regex]::Matches($results , "\w+[('')]") | foreach-object {$_.value }`

Comment: `[regex]::Matches($results , '\W+\w+[('')]\W+' ) | foreach-object {$_.value }`

Comment: How about `$Results | ?{$_ -match "\(([^)]*)"} | %{$Matches[1]}`? That would output `'Start'`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician -  that is a good way too! This helps. I had used the replace function to strip the ticks. `($Results | ?{$_ -match "\(([^)]*)"} | %{$Matches[1]}).replace("'" , "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweaking @TheMadTechnician's regex just a bit, `"\('([^\)']*)'\)"` will get the word between `('` and `')`, without the quotes.  I use the `-match` operator below.  The result you want will be in the `$matches[1]` variable.

```
PS> $results = "All domain controllers have migrated successfully to the Global state ('Start')."
PS> $results -match "\('([^\)']*)'\)"
True
PS> $matches[1]
Start
```

Comment: Awesome! Great job! Thank you for explaining what you did to achieve this. It helps me out a ton!

Answer (score 0):

So, this was the only way I could figure out how to get this. If others are able to give a simpler solution I am all ears. But for now, this is the way I got it to work

`([regex]::Matches($results , '\w+[('')^]' ) | foreach-object {$_.value }).replace("'", "")`